# Basic Understanding of Convolution Operation

Tags: discrete-signals, convolution, continuous-signals, dsp-core

I would really appreciate any help in understanding this.

If $$y[n] = x[n]*r[n]\tag{1}$$ then what is $y[n-n_0]$ for any system?

Is it $$y[n-n_0] = x[n-n_0]*r[n-n_0]\tag{2}$$ 
or    $$y[n-n_0] = x[n-n_0]*r[n]\tag{3}$$ 
or    $$y[n-n_0] = x[n]*r[n-n_0]\tag{4}$$

Will that result (answer to the above) change when we now have an LTI system with $h[n]=r[n]$ being its impulse response?

Thank you very much

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Conflict with the properties of convolution](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/59986/conflict-with-the-properties-of-convolution)

Answer (score 3):

Since $y[n-n_0] = y[n] \ast \delta [n - n_0]$ and convolution is both associative and distributive, is it not the case that

$$
y[n-n_0] = \left(x[n] \ast r[n] \right) \ast \delta[n-n_0] = x[n] \ast r[n-n_0] = x[n-n_0] \ast r[n]?
$$

Answer (score 2):

Why not taking the definition of convolution and see what happens?

$$y[n-n_0] = \sum_k x[k]r[n-n_0-k]$$ which gives $$y[n-n_0] = x[n]*r[n-n_0]$$

Also, since $x[n]*r[n] = r[n]*x[n]$, $$y[n-n_0] = \sum_k r[k]x[n-n_0-k]$$ which gives $$y[n-n_0] = r[n] * x[n-n_0]$$

So both (3) and (4) are correct.

Answer (score 0):

I will go with $(4)$, since it is possible to build a system with $h[n-n_0]$

Comment: Thank you very much @jomegaA, a follow-up question will be why is (3) not true as well since the convolution operation is commutative.

Comment: Practically I may have no influence on the input but I can influence the design of my system.